# Entity level constraints - when and how should the validation be implemented?

Tags: entities, 9

I've created a custom constraint, and set it on an entity in the entity annotation:

```
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "student",
*   label = @Translation("Student"),
    ...
*   constraints = {
*     "StudentConstraints" = {}
*   }
```

I'm finding that the constraints are not called when using the following code:

```
$student = Student::create($array_of_student_stuff);
$student->save();
```

However, they are called if I explicitly validate the entity:

```
$student = Student::create($array_of_student_stuff);
if ($violations = $student->validate()) {
  foreach ($violations as $violation) {
    throw new InvalidStudentParameterException(strip_tags($violation->getMessage()));
  }
}
$student->save();
```

Prior to this debugging, I had expected that by default Drupal would check the constraints when the entity is saved, meaning the above behavior was not what I expected. So my questions are:

1. Is Drupal supposed to be checking entity-level constraints upon save? (This would indicate a problem or something missing in my custom entity code). If Drupal is supposed to be checking constraints upon save by default, where in core does this happen (so I can work backwards to debug)?
2. I see that content entities can have the `validationRequired` property set to `TRUE`. Is it required to set this flag somewhere that will force validation upon save? Maybe that's what I'm missing from my custom code.
3. Or, if Drupal is *not* supposed to execute entity-level constraints upon save by default, is there a reason not to perform validation in an implementation of `::preSave()` in my custom entity? This would result in the entity always being validated upon save, which would seem like a good idea to me, but seeing as the default is not to check constraints upon save, maybe there is a reason not to that I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, the form or Rest API is responsible for validating the entity before saving it.
2. `validationRequired` enforces validation, not by validating the entity, but by raising an exception if you try to save an entity which was not validated.
3. I wouldn't perform validation in a preSave() method. A form or web service will probably have validated the entity already and you are running the code twice.

Comment: Great, thank you.